# check sqlite column type

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I am working on an iOS application that uses a SQLite database.

In the next release of my product, i would like to migrate a table column from `TEXT` to `BLOB`.
I plan to do a `DROP TABLE` followed by a `CREATE TABLE` (we can afford to lose the data, it is not an issue here)

My problem is : how can I check simply from Objective-C if a table's column type is `TEXT` or `BLOB` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is "typeless". This means that you can store any kind of data you want in any column of any table, regardless of the declared data type of that column. You can find more info [here.](http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html)

But, if you want to get the info about the declared data type of a column, you can do that by using the pragma table_info(table_name).

eg.

```
pragma table_info(Setting);
```

Then , you can iterate through the returned resultset and check for the data type you want to check.

Comment: you can , in fact omit data types while creating a table in sqlite3

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer ! I can indeed insert binary data in my column declared as `TEXT`. No need of updating the table.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need this check? You can catch first start after release (use settings for this) and update your table, it will be easier

checking first start after release:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];        
BOOL flag=[prefs boolForKey:SETTINGS_ALREDY_RAN];//will be NO if settings hasn't those parameters, you can change it to version number
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but how can I catch the first start after release ? That seems difficult to test on my development environment, too.

Comment: This is rather bug-prone - I prefer to test the _real_ nature of the table's column rather than test a boolean in preferences that, for a reason or another, might not be in phase with the table structure ?

Comment: well, its your own app and only you can do something with base, after you have doing changes you can change this value in settings, so it will be sync with table struct. I don't now simple way to get sqlite table field types in iOS, especially since they are dynamic